# Can I write a Keras Lambda layer with non-trainable/fixed weights?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, tf.keras

https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

According to here, stateless customer operations can be wrapped to Lambda layers. But if there are trainable variables, we need to implement our own layer.
I want to ask is it possible to use Lambda layer for fixed weights (i.e. pretrained weights)?

If yes, how to make sure the weights are correctly loaded instead of randomly initialized? Since get_weights() won't give you weights in a Lambda layer.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, Lambda layers do not have any weights from the Keras side, you can put some weights inside your lambda function, but these weights cannot be loaded using Keras and are completely invisible to Keras.

So if you want to use pre-trained weights, you have to implement your own layer, so these weights are known to Keras and can be loaded using `load_weights`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply. Wondering if I can load tensorflow checkpoint first to a tensorflow graph before wrapping into a Lambda layer? I tried this way but seems the output is not the same as TF, which means the weights are not loaded or still randomly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are interested in a convolutional layer. I think it is doable with `model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.conv2d(x, kernels))` where `kernels` is a `numpy` matrix with your weights and `K` is the backend.